# YouCompleteMe throwing (35) SSL connect error when installing libclang on Mac Mojave

Tags: vim, libclang, youcompleteme

I have been using YouCompleteMe for a while, but now I want to have also C++ code completion and I can't get it to work.

I followed the build instructions, on the Github page.

This is what I did:

`./install.py --clang-completer`

I get an error telling me the following:

`for file [/Users/moshe/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/../clang_archives/libclang-8.0.0- 
  x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.bz2]
      expected hash: [0900559a7aff8a1156949a53b811d6711f8493938e47f0587c2e5e6a5c4972e8]
        actual hash: [e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855]
             status: [35;"SSL connect error"]`

I tried upgrading curl, openssl  with `brew upgrade` but nothing works.

I even tried to re-install YouCompleteMe nothing worked, if anyone can please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew I was able to do it but very nasty hack.

YouCompleteMe, downloaded libclang under the clang_archives folder, but the install sequence failed because of a hash mismatch, I tried manually fixing this by editing the YouCompleteMe codebase but I was lost.

I tried doing `./install.py --system-libclang -clang-completer`, but because I was using the system libclang I got a slew of linker errors.

To get around using the installer and getting around using system clang, I simply unarchived the libclang.tar file which gave me a .dylib.

Then I was able do move that archived clang and replace the system clang, under `/Applications`.

I ran the command `./install.py --system-libclang -clang-completer` and it built and linked normally!